# Need Oracle query for a BOM IMPLOSION or BOM "WHERE-USED" on Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Working with Oracle DB 10g.

I am tasked with writing an Oracle query for a BOM IMPLOSION commonly known as BOM "WHERE-USED."  Essentially, given an item or part, I need to provide a list of parent items that contain that item or part, if any.

I have recently coded a BOM EXPLOSION using the following SQL which utilizes the START WITH and CONNECT BY syntax to create a heirarchy downward from a parent item.  I found inspiration for the BOM EXPLOSION query at http://www.confluentminds.com/Trainings/SCM/Topic1.1_Ch1_Part5.html

Current BOM EXPLOSION code:

```
/* BOM EXPLOSION */
select distinct
       level,
       sys_connect_by_path(msib.segment1, ' / ') as "PATH",
       msib2.segment1 as "CHILD ITEM AT LEVEL/PATH"
       /*bic.component_item_id,*/
       /*msib.inventory_item_id,*/
       /*msib2.inventory_item_id*/
from   bom.bom_components_b bic,
       bom.bom_structures_b bom,
       inv.mtl_system_items_b msib,
       inv.mtl_system_items_b msib2
where  1=1
       and bic.bill_sequence_id = bom.bill_sequence_id
       and bic.disable_date is null
       and bom.assembly_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
       and bom.organization_id = msib.organization_id
       and bic.component_item_id = msib2.inventory_item_id
       and bom.organization_id = msib2.organization_id
       and bom.organization_id = #### /* organization id here */
       and bic.effectivity_date < sysdate
       and bom.alternate_bom_designator is null
start with msib.segment1 = '$$$$$$$$$$' /* top parent item here */
connect by nocycle prior bic.component_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
order by level
```

Now, I need go from any child item and list all parent items that contain that child item.

I have searched for "oracle bom implosion" and "oracle bom where used" but nothing is obvious to me.  The BOM IMPLOSION seems far less straightforward than the BOM EXPLOSION.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Clint Van Zee

EDIT 02-NOV-2011:

Yes, I want to traverse up a BOM heirarchy and list those items or components where a specified component is used in the bill.

Based on your answer, I looked into the "connect by" relationship and "start with." I think I have a way to do this. I may have been close to the answer without knowing it.

Craig, here is your mock-up with modifications added to prove this out. I also modified the "connect by" and "start with." It {should!} start with the child component and go "upwards" to list those models or components that "use" the specified starting component. To do this, I also removed the "prior" keyword.

```
with data
as
(
    select 'topmodel1' id, 'component1' child_id from dual union all
    select 'topmodel1' id, 'component3' child_id from dual union all
    select 'component2' id, 'component5' child_id from dual union all
    select 'component3' id, 'component4' child_id from dual union all
    select 'component4' id, 'component5' child_id from dual union all
    select 'component5' id, null child_id from dual union all
    select 'topmodel2' id, 'component1' child_id from dual union all
    select 'topmodel2' id, 'component5' child_id from dual union all
    select 'component5' id, null child_id from dual

)
select distinct
       sys_connect_by_path(id, '/') path, child_id, level
from data
start with child_id = 'component5'
connect by id = child_id
order by level
```

This produces the following result:

```
PATH        CHILD_ID    LEVEL
----------- ----------  -----
/component2 component5  1
/component4 component5  1
/topmodel2  component5  1
```

Looking at the mock data, component 5 is "used by" component2, component4, and topmodel2. So, this change seems to do what I intend. I had to add the dreaded "distinct" as it was traversing the same paths more than once.

I think this is getting me closer.

Here are the minimal changes to my BOM EXPLOSION code to do this in reverse:

```
START WITH msib.segment1 = '$$$$$$$$$$' /* child item here */
CONNECT BY nocycle msib.inventory_item_id = bic.component_item_id
ORDER BY level
```

When I apply this change to my SQL script and try it against the actual Oracle data, the CBO is reporting that the cost of searching just one component is out into the stratosphere. So, this method needs tuning.

Comment: Please don't try to [comment on an answer by editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/128174) - either comment, add information to your question, or post an own answer (if it really is an answer and not additional information or comments relating to another answer).

Comment: My apologies.  I don't know if it was an "answer" so much as a change in my viewpoint based on Craig's information.  For what it's worth, this is my first posting to stackoverflow and I didn't see how I could add a lengthy update noting that to Craig.  I will use my original posting for long edits from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are looking for, but it sounds like you are just wanting to climb up the tree instead of down.  This is still possible using the hierarchical query, you just need to change your start with and connect by criteria.

So take a simple example:

```
with data
as
(
    select 1 id, 2 child_id from dual union all
    select 1 id, 3 child_id from dual union all
    select 2 id, 5 child_id from dual union all
    select 3 id, 4 child_id from dual union all
    select 4 id, 5 child_id from dual union all
    select 5 id, null child_id from dual
)
select sys_connect_by_path(id, '/') path, level
from data
start with id = 1
connect by prior child_id = id;
```

That will give you the child paths starting from the top of the tree.  To change this to start at a point in the tree and move upwards, you would simply replace the start with / connect by with something like:

```
start with id = 4 -- or wherever in the tree you want to start and move upwards
connect by prior id = child_id;
```

Hopefully that helps.  If not, if you could give an example of what you are wanting your output to look like it would be very beneficial.

Comment: The mocked data works fine.  The actual business data is failing.  An explain plan for finding just one item shows the cost is in the millions and the bytes returned is in the billions.  I have a feeling that this process is not meant to be something in an ad-hoc query.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see your update.  In your connect by, you will still need the work "prior" to be able to traverse either way correctly.  I am not in front of a database right now, but will put together something with your new example on Monday.

Comment: Thanks.  In my mock code I added "prior" back to it and I get the component3 and topmodel1 (grandparents of component 5), so that is good.  I didn't think of that.  Now I will try and examine this in the actual business data.  The bom structures table has 15m rows and the bom comonents table has 61m rows.

Comment: This solution worked well for small sets of data.  However, given the millions of of rows of data in the tables I am accessing, this method is unusable.  We are revisiting the strategy involved in a "BOM Implosion" or "Where Used" in Oracle.